# SonarQube Error ECONNREFUSED when trying to build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines

**The error message :**

> 2020-10-27T07:09:07.2165374Z ##[section]Starting: Prepare analysis on
> SonarQube 2020-10-27T07:09:07.2173598Z
> ============================================================================== 2020-10-27T07:09:07.2173933Z Task         : Prepare Analysis
> Configuration 2020-10-27T07:09:07.2174239Z Description  : Prepare
> SonarQube analysis configuration 2020-10-27T07:09:07.2174492Z Version
> : 4.11.0 2020-10-27T07:09:07.2174726Z Author       : sonarsource
> 2020-10-27T07:09:07.2175119Z Help         : Version: 4.11.0. [More
> Information](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner-tfs-ts.html)
> 2020-10-27T07:09:07.2175552Z
> ============================================================================== 2020-10-27T07:09:11.0792396Z ##[error][SQ] API GET
> '/api/server/version' failed, error was:
> {"code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":9000}
> 2020-10-27T07:09:11.1210822Z ##[section]Finishing: Prepare analysis on
> SonarQube

It runs on my sonarqube and analysed through sonar scanner, but when i tried to run the pipeline i keep getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your sonarqube server can be accessed from the devops pipeline agents. If your sonarqube server is hosted on local server, you have to create a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) and run your pipeline on this self-hosted agent. It is because cloud agents cannot access to the local sonarqube server.

You can check below steps to configure sonarcloud analysis for your project with devops pipeline.

1, And set up [sonarqube service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#create-a-service-connection) on your azure devops project.

Project settings-->Service connections (under Pipelines)--> New service connection--> Choose Sonarqube. Please refer [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/user-token/) to Get a sonarqube security token

[image]

2, Install Sonarqube extension to your azure devops organization. And add below three sonarqube tasks to the end of your pipeline(after build task). For below example in yaml pipeline.

```
- task: SonarQubePrepare@4
  inputs:
    SonarQube: sonarqubeConnectionName
    scannerMode: CLI
    configFile: sonar-project.properties

- task: SonarQubeAnalyze@4

- task: SonarQubePublish@4
```

3,  Create a `sonar-project.properties` file with below properties in the root of your project. Or add below properties to the `additional Properties`(`extraProperties`) field for SonarQubePrepare task. Click [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-parameters/) for more information

```
sonar.projectKey=projectKey
sonar.projectName=projectName
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=mainsourcefilesfolder #eg. dist
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.tests=testcodesourcefolder
```

Note: SonarQube is only working on the master branch. Please run your pipeline against master branch. Check [this thread](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/community-edition-with-vsts-to-use-the-property-sonar-branch-name-the-branch-plugin-is-required-but-not-installed/1686/5) for more information.